# Uncaught TypeError: pdfMake.createPdf is not a function

Tags: pdfmake

I have trouble using pdfmake, the problem is that I got it working in firefox, but not in edge and I dont know how to debug it. In developer tools I can see that pdfmake module has loaded, but the createPdf function is not available. The code is used on a wordpress site if it has relevance.

I am including pdfmake with the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.71/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.71/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
```

And the error message I can see in my console is

```
Uncaught TypeError: pdfMake.createPdf is not a function
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (all.js?ver=1.1.71:4770:9), <anonymous>:18:10)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (all.js?ver=1.1.71:4770:9)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:43064)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:41048)
eval @ VM208:18
(anonymous) @ all.js?ver=1.1.71:4770
dispatch @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
```

Any ideas how to debug why it is not working?

My code

```
 var docDef={
        content:[
            {text: "hello world"},
        {
          image:'snow'
          
        }  
        ],
        images: {

    // in browser is supported loading images via url (https or http protocol) (minimal version: 0.1.67)
    snow: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'

    }
    };
 pdfMake.createPdf(docDef).download();
```

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: I added my code that I am using for testing, but cannot share the whole page generating this error.

Comment: I think this might have some relation to load order or caching since occasionally I got it working on other browsers, but I need some ideas how to debug this to get it working 100%.

Comment: It seems like a clue to this is how the script is loaded, becaue using <script  type="text/javascript">
[
  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.71/pdfmake.min.js',
  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.71/vfs_fonts.js'
].forEach(function(src) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  script.async = false;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
});
</script>  seems like it is working better.